# UIImage appears 2-3 seconds late on viewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView that I use for users profile pic. But, the image appears late on screen like 2 to 3 seconds. Here is how I download it:

```
      @IBOutlet weak var ProfilePic: UIImageView!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.child(user.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild("imageUrl"){

                self.firebaseStorage.child("users").child(FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_ID).getData(maxSize: 10*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                        let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.ProfilePic.image = userPhoto


                })
            }


        })

    }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i actually solved it and I will post it here if newbies like me encounter the same problem. I used Firebase and SDWebImage. Here is the  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files)  This is from Firebase's official website.

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're running runs on a different Thread, and according to **Apple**, all UI updates must run on the Main Thread. Here's a [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-must-the-UI-always-be-updated-on-Main-Thread/answer/Reinder-de-Vries) that explains why all UI updates must be on the Main Thread

So in your code you just have to use `DispatchQueue` like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // please don't use implicit unwrapping of variables `data!` cause it may cause crashes, use if let statements instead
    if let data = data {
        let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data)
        self.ProfilePic.image = userPhoto
    }
}
```

On a different note:

Please read on [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) coding standards in this [link](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)

Comment: it loads faster now, but it still loads late like 0.5 - 1 sec.

Comment: This is also because you're doing an async call. What happens is the data is still being downloaded from the server which is why it really will load late.

Comment: Thanks for help. but, what can I do about it? how can I load the image instantly?

Comment: You can't, you can either persist the data so that on the second load it would be loaded instantly since you don't need to download it anymore